# How spring data Cassandra handles null while saving

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have a spring boot application with spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra of version-2.1.2.RELEASE.
Need to understand how spring data Cassandra internally handles null in entity while performing insert option.
Using `AsyncCassandraOperations.insert(<T>)` method for persisting these entities. In some cases these entity's few fields may be null. Is this approach impact Cassandra performance or tombstones may create in Cassandra. Or please suggest an ideal approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues if some of the individual fields of an object are null. There are problems if one of the fields that comprise the key is null.

Comment: Is Cassandra create tombstones?